# How to make program work for capital letters

Tags: java, palindrome

```
// The "PalinDrome" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class PalinDrome
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();

        c.println("Please enter a word");
           String word = c.readLine ();
        int i;
        int num = word.length ();
        String str = "";
        for (i = num - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
            str = str + word.charAt (i);
        if (str.equals (word))
            c.println (word + " is a palindrome");
        else
            c.println (word + " is not a palindrome");




        // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console
    } // main method
} // PalinDrome class
```

I have created a palindrome program for my exam project. The program works fine with lower cased letters such as "mom" but will not work when there is a capital letter such as "Mom". Do you have any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: The javadocs for String contains what you are looking for.

Comment: `str.equalsIgnoreCase(word)`

Answer (score 1):

use `String#equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` method, it ignors case considerations.

```
if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
  ...
}else
  ...
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I believe your example code is ignoring case on the `.equalsIgnoreCase`. I have edited it. +1 for being the first correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
if (str.equals (word))
```

to

```
if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
```

to do string comparisons ignoring particular case.

Answer (score 0):

just use the toUppercase ( or toLowerCase)  of the String before you check if its a Palidrome

Answer (score 0):

After reading the `word` variable, modify it to lowercase:
`word = word.toLowerCase()`

The rest can stay the same and it will work.